# Apache2 rewrite with query string escaped twice

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

Using this rule in a virtual host configuration file leads to double escaping of the query parameters:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

For example:

```
http://example.com?f=hello%20world
```

Leads to

```
https://example.com?f=hello%2520world
```

Note the "%25" escaping the "%" sign. Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to add the [[NE]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) (noescape) tag at the end of the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE]
```

This happens because `&` and `?` and some others are escaped by default in the rewrite process.